# What is this keyword referring to?

Tags: java, button, this, actionlistener

I thought I had a decent grasp on the `this` keyword. Something has me confused a little bit.

I have a method that adds an ActionListener to my button. This is what the method looks like

```
public void checkButtonState(){

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){



            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }

        });


    }
```

I also have a constructor method in my class.. which looks like this

```
public CanvasA(){
        try{
            CanvasABackground = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Interface\\src\\01120156745.jpg"));

        }catch(IOException ex){

        }


        setSize(450,490);
        setLayout(null);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(CanvasABackground));
        add(picLabel);
        createEnterButton();
        createCloseButton();
        checkButtonState();
        checkButtonState2();
    }
```

When using the `this` keyword in the constructor, I get many different methods that popup. For example typing `this.` will generate many methods just called `add` and many many others. However, typing `this.` inside the

```
@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
```

method, genereates completely different methods.. basically the `this` keyword is referring to something else. In the first case, it's talking about my `CanvasA` class (which extends JPanel btw). Im curious what `this` is referencng when typed inside the `actionPerformed` method.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where

```
 new ActionListener(){



            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  //here this  referes to  ActionListener
            }

        });
```

is an new Annaymous inner class ,inside that `this`  referes to the current instance of  `ActionListener`

Comment: Thank you very much. Both answers are great. Can only accept one ^_^

Comment: @ElmedinZelenkic No issues,It often happens :P Glad to help you.

Comment: @ElmedinZelenkic Accepts this one as it mentions "anonymous inner class" which is straight to the point. :)

Answer (score 4):

*this* here is referring to your action listener instance.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I suspected but didn't want to assume anything. Now I know. Will accept answer in 10 minutes.